# Pattern of events that leads to a goal

Tags: time-series, modeling

I am not a statistician, so go easy on me here...

I have collected lots of data on the behaviour of customers in a shop.  A customer will enter the shop and a series of events will then take place (eg look at product, look at advert in shop, talk to shop assistant, etc).  Before they leave the shop, some customers will make a purchase.

If my goal is to be able predict which future customers will make a purchase, what statistical analysis should I apply to the data?  I basically want to see if there is a pattern of events that, when followed, will indicate that a customer is more likely to make a purchase.  For example, it may be that customers who look at a particular advert in the shop, then talk to the shop assistant, then touch a product are very likely to go on and purchase.

Comment: Nick, I would consider a binary logistic regression.  Your response variable would be binary - did they purchase or not?  The predictors would be the dummy variables associated with these events - 1 if it happened, 0 otherwise.  You could run this in R (Google for information). You will then see which predictors are significant and which are not.

Comment: Dan, thanks for you comment.  Would this method allow for the order of events?  For example people who talk to the shop assistant first then touch the product might be more likely to purchase than those who touch first and talk second.