# Method needed: parameters leading up to an event

Tags: time-series, recurrent-events

I apologize, this is probably a simple question.

I have 3 or 4 time series variables (temperature, depth, etc.) and I have the times that a specific event occurred (about 100 different events of the same type).

I want to know which of my time series variables are most important to causing the event to happen and what are the threshold values of the time series variables that occur before the event.

I will be expressing the time variables as indexes - in terms of averages over the previous 1, 2, 4, 8 hours.

Therefore I will have for each event the values of several indices (temperature over the last 1 hour, temp over the last 2 hours, ... depth over the last 1 hour... etc.)

Is there a model/method that can help me determine which index is most important and threshold values of each index?

My question is kind-of similar to this one, but not quite: [Pattern of events that leads to a goal](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52605/pattern-of-events-that-leads-to-a-goal)

Comment: 'Cause' is actually a very difficult thing to establish. Association is usually what you get out of statistical analysis. Consider, for example that you're examining relationships between $Y_t$ and $X_{t-k}$ and discover that a shift in $X$ always seems to be followed (about $k$ periods later) by a shift in $Y$. Does a shift in $X$ cause a shift in $Y$? There are many circumstances in which the answer is "clearly not". That said, you might find some of the discussion in the Wikipedia article on [Granger causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality) worth a read.

Comment: Thank you, @Glen_b.  Yes: "cause" was an improper choice of words. Your wikipedia link was helpful.

Comment: If that's an adequate answer to your question, I could post it (maybe expanding on it a little), in order that this question have an answer. Alternatively, since your present question has no answers, you should feel free to change it and ask a new question.